# Looking for advise to create my first neural network to classify text

Tags: mongodb, machine-learning, neural-network

I am very new in this field and I would like to create a Neural Network to classify a dataset that I have in MongoDB. I would like some advise about where should I start, what technology should I use or any tutorial that you think it can help.

If you know about any open source code that already does this, I would love to take a look at it.

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Pick a platform

In essence, you should pick a platform or framework that does much of the dirty work for you and read up on some tutorials for that.

The big choice is between natural language processing frameworks such as NLTK or spaCy or Stanford NLP tools;  or a generic machine learning framework such as Tensorflow or PyTorch.

Text classification is a popular task that's reasonably entry-level, is well supported by pretty much everything (so it's not much to say there in a shopping question, pick whatever you like) and would have a bunch of tutorials available online for any major platform.